# PROBLEM TO SAVE IMAGES WITH TKINTER PYTHON

Tags: python, tkinter

I did some code to save images with PILL but when I want to save some images on different formats like PNG or BMP.

```
class ImagePage(tk.Frame):    
  self.image_image_3 = PhotoImage(
                file=relative_to_assets("image_43.png"))
            image_3 = self.canvas.create_image(
                627.0,
                281.0,
                image=self.image_image_3
            )
  image_3 = self.canvas.create_image(
              627.0,
              281.0,
              image=self.image_image_3
          )
```

There is a code of button to call the function that I want to save with these functions.

```
  self.button_3 = Button(
            image=self.button_image_3,
            borderwidth=0,
            highlightthickness=0,
            command=self.fileSave,
            relief="flat"
        )
```

The function "fileOpen" is correct but the other one "fileSave" shows the message that is showed at the end.

```
def fileOpen(self):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfile(
        mode='rb',
        title='Choose a file',
        filetypes=[ ( "Image files",("*.jpg","*.bmp", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif") ), ("All files", ("*.*"))] )

    if filename == None:
        return
    self.img = PIL.Image.open(filename)
    #self.img = self.img.rotate(90)
    self.resized_image= self.img.resize((275,189), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
    
    self.image_image_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.resized_image)
    image_1 = self.canvas.create_image(
        189.0,
        275.0,
        image=self.image_image_1
    )
def fileSave(self):
    self.img= self.image_image_3
    filename = filedialog.asksaveasfile(
        mode='w',
        title='Choose a file',
        defaultextension=".png",
        filetypes=[ ( "Image files",("*.jpg","*.bmp", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.gif") ), ("All files", ("*.*"))] )

    if filename:
        self.img.save(filename)
```

ERROR CODE:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\AUTOMATIZACIÓN\OneDrive - Asper Coating del Peru S.A.C\Alvaro\Asper\ALVARO\ASPER CODIGO\09.30.21\PORCLASES\clase.py", line 598, in fileSave
    self.img.save(filename)
AttributeError: 'PhotoImage' object has no attribute 'save'
```

Comment: `save` function works with `PIL.Image` class and not with `PhotoImage` class.

Comment: I was trying to change `PothoImage` to `PIL.IMAGE` but now I got this error `image "<PIL.PngImagePlugin.PngImageFile image mode=RGBA size=492x444 at 0x246D139B280>" doesn't exist`

Comment: In which line did you get this error.